# Check a particular string and delete part of string in android

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have a string format stored in shared preference. I would like to check if a particular word exists. If yes, then delete those few words which start from x and ends at y.

Something like this: For example:

```
 String items = "Veggies=Beans-Carrot-Potato-Onions--DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap--Fruits=Apple-Banana-Grapes-Pears";
```

I would like to check if the above string **items** has "DailyUse=" if so delete all the words that are after "DailyUse=" until "--". So that my string looks like:

```
String Newitems = "Veggies=Beans-Carrot-Potato-Onions--Fruits=Apple-Banana-Grapes-Pears";
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
String [] tests = {
                "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap--Veggies=Beans-Carrot-Potato-Onions--DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap--Fruits=Apple-Banana-Grapes-Pears--DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"
                ,"DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"
                ,"DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap--DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"
        };
        String key = "DailyUse";
        for (String test : tests) {
            String newItems = test;
            // Replace only one at beginning
            String regexp = "(^" + key + "=.+?(--|$))";
            while(newItems.matches(regexp)) {
                newItems = newItems.replaceAll(regexp, "");
            }
            // Regex to replace all other
            regexp = "(--" + key + "=.+?)(--|$)";
            newItems = newItems.replaceAll(regexp,"$2");
            System.out.println("Before "  + test);
            System.out.println("After " + newItems);
        }
```

UPDATE based on comments

Comment: Thanks @Jejefcgb, this works fine but what if the items are just one something like this: "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"; Then I don't get " " instead i get "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"

Comment: Hey! can you help me fix this?

Comment: When i executed my example, it seems fine for me. What is the issue ?

Comment: Please try your code when items that has only 1 item or 2 items something like this: For two items String items = "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt--DailyUse=Milk" or For one item try this: String items = "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt" - Both gives the same result instead of items = "" the result gives "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt"...

Comment: Reponse updated. Just one advice, next time be more explicit on what you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String items = "Veggies=Beans-Carrot-Potato-Onions--DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap--Fruits=Apple-Banana-Grapes-Pears";
    String[] newItems = items.split("--");
    System.out.println(newItems[0] + "--"+ newItems[2]);

}
```

Comment: The problem here is that DailyUse is not hardcoded. It is dynamic. So the string can be first and third. In this case your code might not work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put the DailyUse element in first, second and third position and this code seems to work. I think it can be improved, but here's an idea.

```
    String items = "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap--Veggies=Beans-Carrot-Potato-Onions--Fruits=Apple-Banana-Grapes-Pears";
    String result = "";

    if (items.contains("--DailyUse=")){     // not in first position
        String[] a = items.split("--DailyUse=");

        result = a[0];

        if (a[1].contains("--")){       // Daily use is not the last element
            String[] b = a[1].split("--");
            result = result + "--" + b[1] ;
        }

    }
    else if (items.contains("DailyUse=")){      // first position

        String[] b = items.split("--");
        result =  items.replace(b[0]+"--", ""); // Delete the dailyuse part

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jejefcgb, this works fine but what if the items are just one something like this: "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"; Then I don't get " " instead i get "DailyUse=Milk-Yogurt-Soap"

Comment: Hey! can you help me fix this?

Comment: I didn't have internet this week end. I'm going to look at this in a few minutes

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write the code but I'll give you a hint. If there is only the DailyUse element, it means that there is no "--". So basically, your String will start with "DailyUse" and you just need to check if the String contains "--" or not.